# Form does not perform the second register

Tags: php, ajax

After made a newsletter registration, I try to make a new one, and then this second fails. The answer I get is this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#newsletter-form").submit(function(){

                var valor = $("input[name=newsletter]").val(); 

                if (valor != "" ) {

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "newsletter.php",
                    data: $("#newsletter").serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#Resposta").removeClass('sucesso');
                        $("#Resposta").addClass(msg.status);
                        $("#Resposta").html(msg.message);

                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $("#Resposta").removeClass('erro');
                        $("#Resposta").addClass('erro');
                        $("#Resposta").html(msg.message);
                    }
                });
                return false;   
                }   
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is the form:

```
<form action="newsletter.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="content-form clearfix" id="newsletter-form">
```

The example can be seen here:
[Page:](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/)

Comment: "try to make a new then I'm not getting" — I have no idea what this means.

Comment: what is that you r trying to make new? And why is the form tag enctyppe is multipart, r u planning to upload any document?

Comment: Hello @Pundit, I'm trying to send a second record.

Answer (score 0):

I retraced my code for the registration of my newsletter, see:

```
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").on("click", function(event){
        var email       = $("#newsletter").val();
        var emailFilter = /^.+@.+\..{2,}$/;
        var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\/\"\[\]]/;

        if((emailFilter.test(email))||email.match(illegalChars)){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "newsletter.php",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $(".status").html('enviando...');
                },
                data: {'email':email},
                success: function(json){
                    if(json.tipo == "0"){ // erro
                        $(".status").html("<span class='erro'>"+json.msg+"</span>");
                    }else{ // sucesso
                        $(".status").html("<span class='sucesso'>"+json.msg+"</span>");
                        cleanFields();
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            $(".status").html("<p style='color:#f25824'>Por favor, informe um e-mail válido.</p>");
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#newsletter').focus(clean);

    function clean(){
        $(".status").html("");
    }

    function cleanFields(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#newsletter").val("");
        }, 3000);
    }
}); 

</script>
```

Thanks for the great tips.